# Condition to stop a java iteration

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements, break

Good evening. I'm having trouble finding a condition that would stop a loop inside my program. I will try and explain it as generally as possible so the question might help others in the same situation:

I have a collection of objects.
With a piece of code inside the loop, I generate more objects.
I want to add these objects to the collection.
Once they're added I'd like to iterate over them UNLESS they've been iterated over before.

Pseudo-code:

```
While (!everyObjectHasBeenIteratedOver){
    for (Object o : SetOfObjects){
        // Generate an unknown number of objects
        // Add those objects to the SetOfObjects unless they're already there
    }
}
```

So that's basically it.
The only answer I know is by using Lists, which support the addition of elements over the iterating list without breaking up, however I, personally, am using HashSets.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advanced.

EDIT: Ended up using a set for the visited objects and another one for the not visited.
Condition: `while (!notVisited.isEmpty()) {...}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose to use 2 collections: visited and toBeVisited. Visited may be Set and toBeVisited - Queue. So you add new items to queue only if they not visited yet. And when you add item to Queue, you also add it to Set.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I can't believe I didn't think of it like that. I'll give it a try and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to a set will do nothing if the object is already there. So that shouldn't be a problem. If the object has the same identity (remember to override `hashCode()` and `equals(..)`), but different other fields, you can check with `set.contains(..)`

If you want to iterate some collection, modify it, but continue iterating on the original one, then make a copy at the start, and iterate the copy, while adding to the original.

Comment: I know, but the loop continues on forever. That is partially why I'm using sets, allowing me to avoid using .contains(), .containsAll() or checking for order. :(

Comment: Wouldn't modifying the original collection cause a Concurrent error?

Comment: @JSG_ESP if you are iterating the copy - no. If you are iterating the original - it depends on how you iterate it.

Comment: Attempting to modify a `java.util.Collection` while iterating over its elements will likely cause an instance of `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` to be thrown. Be sure to check the documentation of the concrete subclasses of `Collection` that you are using.

Comment: @Bozho So, on your second paragraph "modify it, but continue iterating on the original one [...] while adding to the original". Wouldn't that cause the exception?  
Sorry, I might've understood wrong.

Comment: Yes, that's the precondition - If you want to do that, then you'd need a copy (otherwise you risk the exception)

Comment: @Bozho This would be somewhat similar to what I've done:  
`Beginning of the loop`
`copy original_set to iterating_set`
`Iterate over iterating_set and add new ones to original_set`
However, when it finishes adding and goes back to the beginning of the loop, it iterates AGAIN over the first element.

Comment: I'm going to try and use two sets as Nikita pointed out (Visited and Not Visited). Be back in a bit to let you know how it went!

Thank you very much anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a recursive approach

```
public doSomething(Collection<Object> doTo, Set<Object> beenDone) {
  for(Object o : collection) {
    Collection<Object> newObjects = createObjects(0);
    doSomething(newObjects,beenDone);
    beenDone.add(o);
  }
   return beenDone;
}

public mainIteration(Collection<Object> collection) {
  Set<Object> operatedOn = new HashSet<Object>();
  doSomething(collection,operatedOn);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, ended up using two sets (Visited and Unvisited) to do the job. Granted the recursive approach looks more elegant than what I used...